# How do I create a read-only ACL for Consul so that Datadog can monitor it?

Tags: consul, datadog

I have a 3-node Consul setup. I've bootstrapped the ACL system as per [their docs](https://developer.hashicorp.com/consul/tutorials/security/access-control-setup-production)

I wish to monitor it with Datadog. The [docs for Datadog's Consul integration](https://us5.datadoghq.com/integrations/consul?search=consul) do not call out the need for an ACL token, so Datadog agent gets this error when trying to access Consul:

```
403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://localhost:8500/v1/agent/self
```

I created a policy with the following rules: readonly-policy.hcl

```
agent "" {
  policy = "read"
}
key_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
node_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
```

and then created a token for that policy, and added acl_token to the Datadog agent's Consul configuration like so:

```
init_config:
  service: consul

instances:
  ## @param url - string - required
  ## Where your Consul HTTP server lives,
  ## point the URL at the leader to get metrics about your Consul cluster.
  ## Use HTTPS instead of HTTP if your Consul setup is configured to do so.
  #
  - url: http://localhost:8500
    acl_token: REDACTED

logs:
  - type: file
    path: /var/log/consul_server.log
    source: consul
    service: consul
```

But I'm still encountering the error.

If I set acl_token to the bootstrap management token I created, it does work (Datadog can collect data from Consul), but I'd rather have Datadog using a more restricted token just in case.

What rule(s) am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

This rule set appears to allow the necessary read operations.

```
agent_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
operator_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
key_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
node_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
service_prefix "" {
  policy = "read"
}
acl = "read"
```